# Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'Question'

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know how to call the result from a class inside another; I'm trying to get a shuffled list from another class but it says `A value of type 'Question' can't be returned from the function 'questions' because it has a return type of 'List<Question>'`. When I place the method just before I call `List<Question> get questions => this._questions;` it works but I can't track the order of options so every time I choice one option it is always wrong even being correct. So I move the method to where the list is being made and shuffle when questions are called. This is the method:

```
List<Question> _questions = sample_data.map((question) {
    // shuffle the options
    List<String> options = question["options"];
    //print(options);
    options.shuffle();
    print(options);
    return Question(
        id: question['id'],
        question: question['question'],
        options: options,
        answer: question['answer']);
  }).toList()
    ..shuffle();
```

This was placed here and works but I couldn't track the order of options because it looks like shuffle the order of indexes;

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/state_manager.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/models/Questions.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/score/score_screen.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/screens/welcome/welcome_screen.dart';

// We use get package for our state management

class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  // Lets animated our progress bar

  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;
  // so that we can access our animation outside
  Animation get animation => this._animation;

  PageController _pageController;
  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

// remove this shuffle to check if options are shuffled

  Question _questions = Get.put(Question());

  //


  WAS HERE


  //

  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;

  bool _isAnswered = false;
  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  String _correctAns;
  String get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;
  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  int _indexQ;
  int get indexQ => this._indexQ;

  // for more about obs please check documentation
  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;
  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;
  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  // called immediately after the widget is allocated memory
  @override
  void onInit() {
    // Our animation duration is 60 s
    // so our plan is to fill the progress bar within 60s
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 60), vsync: this);
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        // update like setState
        update();
      });

    // start our animation
    // Once 30s is completed go to the next qn
    _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    _pageController = PageController();

    super.onInit();

    if (_questionNumber == _questions.length) {
      reset();
      Get.to(WelcomeScreen());
      _animationController.reset();
    }
  }

  // // called just before the Controller is deleted from memory
  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    _animationController.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    // because once user press any option then it will run
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer;
    _indexQ = question.options.indexOf("Google");
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    print(indexQ);
    print(_selectedAns);
    print(question.options);

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    // It will stop the counter
    _animationController.stop();
    update();

    // Once user select an ans after 2s it will go to the next qn
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
      _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);

      // Reset the counter
      _animationController.reset();

      // Then start it again
      // Once timer is finish go to the next qn
      _animationController.forward().whenComplete(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      // Get package provide us simple way to naviigate another page
      Get.to(ScoreScreen());
    }
  }

  void updateTheQnNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
  }

  void reset() {
    _isAnswered = false;
    _correctAns = '';
    _selectedAns = 0;
    _questionNumber = 1.obs;
    _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

    //Get.to(WelcomeScreen());
  }
}
```

So I pick that method and place at the end of the list being made.

```
class Question {
  final int id;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;
  final String answer;

  Question({
    this.id = 0,
    this.question = '',
    this.options = const <String>[],
    this.answer = '',
  });
}

void main() async {
 List sample_data = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question":
          "Flutter is an open-source UI software development kit created by ______",
      "options": ['Apple', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Microsoft'],
      "answer_index": 'Google',
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "When google release Flutter.",
      "options": ['Jun 2017', 'Jun 2017', 'May 2017', 'May 2018'],
      "answer_index": 'May 2017',
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "A memory location that holds a single letter or number.",
      "options": ['Double', 'Int', 'Char', 'Word'],
      "answer_index": 'Char',
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "question": "What command do you use to output data to the screen?",
      "options": ['Cin', 'Count>>', 'Cout', 'Output>>'],
      "answer_index": 'Cout',
    },
  ];

  List<Question> _questions = sample_data.map((question) {
    // shuffle the options
    List<String> options = question["options"];
    //print(options);
    options.shuffle();
    print(options);
    return Question(
        id: question['id'],
        question: question['question'],
        options: options,
        answer: question['answer']);
  }).toList()
    ..shuffle();
  
  
}
```

The question is that I don't know how to acess this from class it was before.

Comment: You again what is the problem now ? :D You did not  explain it very well.

Comment: I think you should change `Question _questions` to this `List<Question> _questions`

Comment: And to track the answer you should forget tracking it with indexes, instead use literal value

Comment: Yeah it me again, sorry :/ I'm new to dart/flutter coming from Python. I'll try this.

Comment: I put like this `List<Question> _questions = Get.put(Question());` but gives the error `The argument type 'Question' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Question>'`

Comment: what is this `Get.put(Question())` ?

Comment: Is to get the Class Question I guess

Comment: Should not it be like this: `List<Question> _questions = sample_data.map((question) {.........`

Comment: It is actually working but, I putted it inside the void main() async and I dont know how to call it.

Comment: The code I have posted for you, is example code you should not put it in void main async, you should put map function in the QuestionController and when you call the QuestionController pass the required map to be aprsed into Question and shuffeled.

Comment: After some hours, I finally solved!, I moved only one line to where the option card is being created, this is the line `List _options = question.options.toList()..shuffle();` so when I press the correct card it trigger one method passing the selected option and comparing if is the right option, Thanks so much!

Comment: I am very glad you figured it out <3 good luck.